# How to detect JPEG's compression value in IOS ?

Tags: ios, swift, jpeg

I am trying to calculate image size from total bytes

> UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75)?.count

But the Data I get is already compressed. How would i convert UIImage, which is a JPEG, to Data with actual compression value ?

Comment: So either i should get the actual compression value or there should be a way to convert  JPEG to data without changing actual compression value

Comment: If you are lucky, you can find something like "Compressed bits per pixel" in the meta data, e.g. exif data, via some kind of meta-data viewer (google for "exif viewer online"). Also if you are lucky, swift would have some API to query that information, or, less lucky, swift would provide some API to query exif info as key/value pair. Good luck.